# How do I proxy every request from a dotnet core app running in a docker container

Tags: c#, docker, proxy, .net-core

I'm struggling to get my http calls from a web api running on a docker container proxy http requests. I've successfully reached the desired endpoint by proxy using bash

```
docker exec -i -t 665b4a1e17b6 /bin/bash
```

and

```
http_proxy=http://exampleProxy:7777 curl -s http://endpoint
```

Now I want to recreate this from within the app running on the same container

I have tried the following:

1. [dotnet core proxy](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/dev/samples/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy.Samples/Startup.cs)

   ```
       loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
       loggerFactory.AddDebug();

       app.UseMvc().RunProxy(new ProxyOptions
       {
           Scheme = "http",
           Host = "example",
           Port = "7777"
       });
   ```
2. Setting the http_proxy environment variable upon container creation

   ```
       export http_proxy=http://example:7777
   ```
3. Using HttpClientHandler

   ```
   var handler = new HttpClientHandler
   {
       Proxy = new WebProxy("http://example:777)
   };
   var client = new HttpClient(handler);
   etc....
   ```

Can anyone think of other ways to set up a proxy? or any advice on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I not a dotnet expert and not sure how your app run, so I just assume you run your app like a normal nginx.
I suggest you run your app like this `sh -c your_app`, which means you can set your docker cmd to `sh -c your_app`.

Hope this will solve your problem.

BTW, this problem isn't related with kubernetes, you may have a wrong tag;)